# how to deploy gulp angularjs project on IIS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, gulp, gulp-sass

how to publish gulp angularjs project on IIS, i deploy my project on iss but its show below picture error , 
i was run this command `gulp build` .
when i run my project on visual studio code using `gulp serve`  , its working fine

[image]

[image]